# How do I export data from a GridView to a .txt

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a C# asp.net project and can't seem to get the "exporting to a .txt file from a grid view" to work.

```
protected void ExportGridToText() {
    BindGridView();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    StringBuilder Rowbind = new StringBuilder();
    Response.ContentType = "application/text";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=GlogData.txt");
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
    Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    gvLog.DataBind();



    for (int i = 2; i < gvLog.Columns.Count; i++)
    {

        Rowbind.Append("\"" + gvLog.Columns[i].HeaderText + "\"" + ',');
    }

    Rowbind.Append("\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < gvLog.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < gvLog.Columns.Count; k++)
        {

            Rowbind.Append("\"" + gvLog.Rows[j].Cells[k].Text + "\"" + ',');
            Rowbind.Replace("&lt;", "<");
            Rowbind.Replace("&gt;", ">");
        }

        Rowbind.Append("\n");
    }


    gvLog.AllowPaging = false;
    Response.Output.Write(Rowbind.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

}
```

Evrytime I run the code I get a error message:

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed

Why is it giving me this error?

How do I fix it?

Is it possible to get the data from the source... This is under the get Button that populates the GridView:

```
protected void GetLogBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string sBeginDate = BeginDate.Text;
        string sEndDate = EndDate.Text;
        JObject vResultJson = new JObject();
        FKWebCmdTrans cmdTrans = new FKWebCmdTrans();
        DateTime dtBegin, dtEnd;
        if (sBeginDate.Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                dtBegin = Convert.ToDateTime(sBeginDate);
                sBeginDate = FKWebTools.GetFKTimeString14(dtBegin);
                vResultJson.Add("begin_time", sBeginDate);

            }
            catch
            {

                BeginDate.Text = "";
            }
        }

        if (sEndDate.Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                dtEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(sEndDate);
                sEndDate = FKWebTools.GetFKTimeString14(dtEnd);
                vResultJson.Add("end_time", sEndDate);

            }
            catch
            {

                EndDate.Text = "";
            }
        }

        try
        {
            string sFinal = vResultJson.ToString(Formatting.None);
            byte[] strParam = new byte[0];
            cmdTrans.CreateBSCommBufferFromString(sFinal, out strParam);
            mTransIdTxt.Text = FKWebTools.MakeCmd(msqlConn, "GET_LOG_DATA", mDevId, strParam);
            Session["operation"] = GET_LOG_DATA;
            GetLogBtn.Enabled = false;
            ClearBtn.Enabled = false;
             Timer.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusTxt.Text = "Fail! Get Log Data! " + ex.ToString();
        }

    }
```

This is under the BindGridView:

```
private void BindGridView()
    {
           try
        {

            string mTransid = mTransIdTxt.Text;

            string strSelectCmd = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_fkcmd_trans_cmd_result_log_data where trans_id = '" + mTransid + "'";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strSelectCmd, msqlConn);
            SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (sqlReader.HasRows)
            {
                if (sqlReader.Read())
                    nCount = sqlReader.GetInt32(0);
             }
             sqlReader.Close();
             sqlCmd.Dispose();

            {
                  DataSet dsLog = new DataSet();


                strSelectCmd = "SELECT * FROM tbl_fkcmd_trans_cmd_result_log_data where trans_id = '" + mTransid + "'";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSelectCmd, msqlConn);
               // conn.Open();
                da.Fill(dsLog, "tbl_fkcmd_trans_cmd_result_log_data");

                DataView dvLog = dsLog.Tables["tbl_fkcmd_trans_cmd_result_log_data"].DefaultView;

                gvLog.DataSource = dvLog;
                gvLog.DataBind();

                StatusTxt.Text = "       Total Count : " + Convert.ToString(nCount) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Current Time :" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusTxt.Text = ex.ToString();
        }

    }
```

I hope this helps

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to export a GridView? Why not export the underlying data that you bind to it instead?

Comment: Where is the `Response.End();`?

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it

Comment: You cannot export a file in an UpdatePanel.

Comment: @mason I did not work on the original project... I only want to add a export button

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez It's there ... Scroll down

Comment: @mason how do I go about exporting the data from the bind?... or can I intercept the data before it goes to the GridView and store it in memory and every time I press the "save to .txt" button , it exports the data that was stored?

Comment: Where is the data source set for the GridView? You didn't show that in your question.

Comment: The data comes from a SQL db that, for me anyway, doesn't look like it stores the data... I'll add the code now

Comment: Stop what you're doing and fix your SQL Injection vulnerabilities. Learn how to use parameterized queries. Now.

Comment: @JonP I have no idea what your talking about... i don't know SQL and only recently started with c#

I'm a noob

Comment: https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries - If this system takes user input it will only be a matter of time until you find "interesting" data in your system or worse still, missing tables. Even worse if this is a publically accessible site.

Comment: I'm going to dispense some tough love.... that SQL, as written, has no place in a production system and if this is anything more than a school project it should be fixed as the **highest priority**. All it will take is one malicious user, disgruntled employee etc to seriously compromise your entire database and/or system. Not just on this page, but anywhere a SQL Query is formed using string concatenation.

Comment: I'm not even sure why the original developer used SQL... All the program is supposed to do is get and send information from and to a network connected device... all i need is to add a button that exports the data on screen to a text file...

Comment: It doesn't matter why. It is there and is a **massive security hole**. Either work out how to replace the SQL or fix it. If this is code in production,  in my opinion, everything else can wait - it is that serious.

Comment: wow... I had no idea... I'm checking out the link above now..

Answer (score 0):

Following Code is For Excel Mainly...but its successfully converting gridview to .txt file just need a little workaround..

```
public void ExportToExcel(System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView controlname, string sheetname)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Response.ClearContent();
        context.Response.Buffer = true;
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", sheetname + ".txt"));
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/text";
       // context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", sheetname + ".xls"));
       // context.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        //Change the Header Row back to white color
        controlname.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
        //Applying stlye to gridview header cells
        for (int i = 0; i < controlname.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            controlname.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#507CD1");
        }
        int j = 1;
        //This loop is used to apply stlye to cells based on particular row
        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in controlname.Rows)
        {
            gvrow.BackColor = Color.White;
            if (j <= controlname.Rows.Count)
            {
                if (j % 2 != 0)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < gvrow.Cells.Count; k++)
                    {
                        gvrow.Cells[k].Style.Add("background-color", "#EFF3FB");
                    }
                }
            }
            j++;
        }
        controlname.RenderControl(htw);
        context.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        context.Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: I used your code and get a error "Control 'gvLog' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server"... I'm a noob... thanks for the help

Comment: just add a  <form id="form1" runat="server"> after body tag

Comment: Do you Know why it gives the error even though The <form id="form1" runat="server"> is there?

Comment: Control 'gvLog' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server" error says it all....place inside a <form> gridview </form>